# How to change password to an arbitrary string and re-apply the password policy using LDAP and C#?

Tags: c#, passwords, ldap, reset, policy

Hi I am trying to reset a user's password to 'reset' then for the user to change it once they log in.  Since we have some rules in our password policy to disallow such a simple password, we first remove the policy then set the password then reapply the policy.  However when they login and try to change their password, using one of the old passwords still works.  We have pwdInHistory value set to 5.  Here is the code:

```
 de.Properties["pwdPolicySubentry"].Value = "";
 de.CommitChanges();
 changePassword(uid, "", "reset");
 de.Properties["pwdPolicySubentry"].Value = POLICY;
 de.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: I believe if you use LDAP setPassword instead of changePassword as an administrative user, it ignores password policy.  That would be a lot simpler than dynamically re-assigning the policy.

Comment: What about setting the password to one that matches your policy ?

Comment: @mellamokb oh changePassword is our own code

Comment: de.Properties["userPassword"].Value = newPassword;
de.CommitChanges();

Answer (score 0):

Your LDAP may support RFC3062, i.e. it can generate a new policy-compliant password for you. Eliminates the entire problem.